# GUI-Toolkit that supports propely OpenGL3

Tags: c++, winapi, wxwidgets, opengl-3

I am in need of a GUI-Toolkit that properly supports OpenGL3 and allow creating of a  forward compatible profile.

Normally I use wxWidgets. But when I try to create the context I use in my engine on a wxWindow or wxPanel, GetDC() fails because the Window lacks CS_OWNDC.
I really don't want to learn QT, but it does not support it either from my first looks.

So, how can I either create a proper Canvas on a wxWindow or what Toolkit supports my needs? 
Thanks for any input.

Comment: Do you really need a lot of GUI functionality (forms, menus, ...) or will a simple multimedia manager suffice?

Comment: Yep, I need a lot of GUI functionality. Forms, Menus, Lists, Property Grids etc. Too much to implement it with OpenGL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt supports forward compatible contexts in versions 4.7 and above:
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qglformat.html

Comment: Uhm, thanks for the pointer. Somehow I missed it with QT. I was googling for QT and OGL3 but only found posts that say it doesn't support it :).